# Applying conditions on Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame [df] as follows:

```
ID  Status  
1   Success
2   Success
3   Fail
4   nan
```

Essentially, if all the Statuses are Success I want to print "Success" else "Fail". Seems pretty straightforward but I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am trying the following code:

```
if df['Status'].values.all() == "SUCCESSFUL":
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
else:
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
```

OR

```
if df['Status'].isnull().values.any() == False and df['Status'].values.all() == "SUCCESSFUL":
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
elif df['Status'].isnull().values.any() == True or df['Status'].values.any() != "SUCCESSFUL":
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
```

None of these approaches seem to work. They give me the result as "Success".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should doing the `all` with the boolean

```
if ((df['Status'] == "SUCCESSFUL") |(df['Status'].isnull())).all():
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
else:
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
================================================================================================================================
Fail
```

Comment: ```
if (df['Status'] == "SUCCESSFUL").all():  
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
else:
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
```
Is all I needed since I only want to disply "Success" if all values are "Success". If any value is blank(nan) or anything else other than SUCCESSFUL, then it should  disply "Fail".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (df['Status']=='Fail').any():
    print('Failed')
else:
    print('Passed')
```

or

```
if (df['Status']=='Success').all():
    print('Passed')
else:
    print('Failed')
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (df['Status'] == 'Success').all():
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
else:
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if df['Status'].size == sum(df['Status'] == 'Success'):
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Success")
else:
    print("=" * 128 + "\n" + "Fail")
```